# WinAPI Methodology to Detect Button Swiping/Dragging

Tags: winapi, touch

I have a virtual keyboard and I am trying to figure out a way to detect the user swiping keys, ie, pressing one winapi button control down (for eg 'Q') then moving the mouse/finger around over other keys to type out words. For a better description see the below image.

[image]

Currently the only solution I can think of is detect a `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` on a button. Then detect `WM_MOUSEMOVE` events over other buttons (by hit testing?) and record that key. When I next receive a `WM_LBUTTONUP` I know the user is finished typing. I've also tried to detect `WM_TOUCH` and `WM_TOUCHHITTESTING` events but on a Surface Pro 3 these events are not firing but this could be I need to register for these events?

Is there an existing WinAPI function/methodology I could use that I am unaware of?

Comment: No, there is nothing built into the system, you'll have to roll your own. You scheme working off of `WM_MOUSEMOVE` won't work, though: When pressing a button, that button captures mouse input, i.e. all mouse input goes to that button. To receive `WM_TOUCH` messages you have to call [RegisterTouchWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317326.aspx) first. Regardless, it is pretty unclear, what you are really trying to achieve here. Are you using native Windows controls? Are those custom controls? Are they window-less?

Comment: @IInspectable they are standard winapi button controls whose parent is a subclassed static control. currently the static is receiving the mouse move messages.

Comment: Do away with the button controls, just draw them yourself in a custom window class. Then tracking mouse input should be relatively simple.